# Check for a value in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, match

I'm trying to check for match in an array with **PURE JAVASCRIPT**. I don't know how to do this, I would appreciate your help.

```
var sites = new Array ("site1.com", "site2.com", "site3.com" ...);
// Sites array contains 100 values

var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        img = imgs[i].src;

        // I'm trying to check if is in array, 
        // and don't waste a lot of size in code

        if(img.match(sites)){
            notHere(imgs[i]);
        }

        // This is the working way.
        // Even if location is a.site1.com/b/, it will match 
        if (img.match("site1.com")) {
            heReload(imgs[i]);
        }
        // Repeat this piece of code 100 times
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: I don't want to check for an exact value. I want to simulate the `match()` function so if img = "http://a.b.c/d/" and in array is "b.c/", it executes `function()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "sites" variable should be a regular expression rather than an array:

```
 var sites = /\b(site1\.com|site2\.com|etc|etc)\b/
```

later:

```
 if (img.match(sites))
    ......
```

If for some reason you prefer to keep "sites" in an array, you also can create a regular expression "on the fly":

```
var sites = ["site1.com", "site2.com", "site3.com"]
var sitesRegexp = new RegExp("\\b(" + sites.join("|").replace(".", "\\.") + ")\\b")

 ....

 if (img.match(sitesRegexp)
    ......
```

Comment: **Do not forget to escape special RegEx characters!** A dot is not the only special character. `.replace(/[[^$.|?*+(){}\\]/g, '\\$&');`

Answer (score 1):

Good use case for filter.

If you want to have it working on "old" browser :

```
var nativeFilter = Array.prototype.filter;
_.filter = _.select = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    var results = [];
    if (obj == null) return results;
    if (nativeFilter && obj.filter === nativeFilter) return obj.filter(iterator, context);
    each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
      if (iterator.call(context, value, index, list)) results[results.length] = value;
    });
    return results;
};
```

It will return an empty array if nothing is found, otherwise, return an array containing the result(s)

```
> [1,2,3,4].filter(function(item) { return item == 4 } );
[ 4 ]
```

Source : [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html)

So now your code will look like this :

```
var sites = new Array ("site1.com", "site2.com", "site3.com" ...);
// Sites array contains 100 values

var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName( "img" );
for ( var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++ ) {
    var img = imgs[ i ].src;
    var result = sites._filter( function( site ) {
        return img.match( site )
    });

    // result is an array of matching sites

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extend the Array prototype , so it supports all browsers ...

try this :

```
Array.prototype.myContains = function(obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {if (this[i] .indexOf(obj)>-1)  return true; }
    return false;
}
```

usage : `var t=myArr.myContains(3);`